# What starting AC and HP does a quadruped eidolon have?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, summoner

I'm new to Pathfinder and am trying to create a quadruped eidolon for my summoner. How do I determine its armor class and hit points?

Answer (score 2):

Both the [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons) of the traditional [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) and the [eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained) of the [unchained summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained) start with 1d10 hp from its 1 outsider Hit Die (and see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45126/8610)) but no initial bonus to their Armor Classes beyond what their ability scores and base forms provide (a quadruped base form of either eidolon type gains a +2 natural bonus to Armor Class, for instance). Either eidolon's number of Hit Dice, bonus to Armor Class (which can be split as the summoner picks between an armor bonus and a natural bonus), and other special abilities increase as the [traditional](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons) or [unchained](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) summoner advances in levels.